# Rescue Authentication Error while retrieving contacts from cardmagic/contacts gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, exception, import-contacts

I am using [cardmagic/contacts](https://github.com/cardmagic/contacts) gem to import contacts from email addresses in my application. It is working fine but my problem is I want to catch the **authentication error** like wrong username/password for following code.

```
@contacts = Contacts.guess(@username, @password)
```

I want to display that error to user.

I have tried this but not working for me.

```
@contacts = Contacts.guess(@username, @password)  rescue Contacts::AuthenticationError
```

So please guide me how to do so.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def import
  @username = params[:user]
  @password = params[:pass]
  begin
    @contacts = Contacts.guess(@username, @password)  
  rescue
    @error_message = e.message
    render :action => 'new'
  end
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

## new.html.erb:

```
<% if @error_message %>
  <%= @error_message %>
<% end %>
HTML to get username & password inputs
```

Comment: Hey Arun thank sfor quick reply but still it is not catching the error even if I am entering anything random values in eamil & password field.My application is just displaying exceptions for captcha or yahoo have changed its protocol etc.Do you have any idea to solve the problem?

Comment: Can you please post us the exception you are getting?

Comment: GData::Client::CaptchaError in InvitationsController#import_contacts     CaptchaRequired : Captcha?ctoken=zYyBi97vDOUWnh3I-kIOkLt34aqHj6Q_EpVlzCw4fbqxlswgL08KNxoyHe1hubDqMzi7RCXaG_YpNpmIRcgOn11CHNTRL6uRC5T79Y%3AM2hcehJllGlPV27H6QzSFw

Comment: See the edited answer.. Simply have rescue by removing this from the rescue statement: Contacts::AuthenticationError => e